# Android Studio BottomNavigationView show fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile

I'm starting JAVA studies for the android platform. (Sorry for bad english, I'm using the translator).I would like to know how I can show a fragment when selecting an item in the toolbar.

Fragment Java Files:

- VisaoGeralFragment
- AgendaFragment
- MuralFragment

Fragment Layout Files:

- fragment_visao_geral.xml
- fragment_agenda.xml
- fragment_mural.xml

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_vgeral:
                // Show VisaoGeralFragment
                return true;
                case R.id.navigation_agenda:
                // Show AgendaFragment
                return true;
                case R.id.navigation_mural:
                // Show MuralFragment
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your activity_main you should create a Layout( preferably Frame Layout) where your fragments will appear when you navigate on navigator. Also,
 you have to set an id for that layout.
Below is the code that you will use:

```
Fragment frag = new YourFragment();

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.id_of_your_frame, frag);
trans.commit();
```

You have to place this code for every case, by changing `YourFragment()` part with related fragment class.
Do not forget to change the `id_of_your_frame` with yours.

Comment: You should change import.support.v4.app.Fragment to import android.support.Fragment

Comment: My bad, I should have written import android.app.Fragment

Comment: Thanks, I also had to replace in the class of fragments

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I tested it with the bar and nothing happened after that I tried with a button and the application stopped

Comment: YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment ();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit(); You could use that instead

Comment: How did you implement your fragments? Did you use onCreateView()?

Comment: I found a source code in github, and I'm going to study it. Thank you very much ;D